# Karaf add additional property to existing config file

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf, blueprint-osgi

I have a bundle which uses a configuration file `org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.config.cfg` with one property:

```
org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.msg="I am a HelloServiceConfig!!"
```

My blueprint for using ConfigAdmin is like:

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.config" update-strategy="reload" >
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.msg" value="Hello World!"/>
</cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>



<bean   id="hello-service-config"
        class="org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.config.internal.HelloServiceConfig"
        init-method="startup"
        destroy-method="shutdown">

    <property name="helloServiceConfiguration">
        <props>
              <prop key="org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.msg" value="${org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.msg}"/>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<service ref="hello-service-config" interface="org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.IHelloService" />
```

This works fine as long as I can change the value of the property and the bundle automatically updates the property.

I am wondering if there's any way of adding a new property to my config file without having to change the blueprint (which involves compile/package again).Of course my bundle should be ready to handle new properties.

Not sure if this makes sense in OSGi. Can anyone give me a hint of how to dynamically add new properties to an existing configuration file and make them available in ConfigAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@yodamad showed me that properties were being updated in my ConfigurationAdmin service, but unfortunately my bundel was not receiving the new properties because in the bean definition I was just using a fixed property.

Finally in order to get new properties from config files I have changed my blueprint definition as follows:

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.config" update-strategy="reload" >
</cm:property-placeholder>

<bean   id="hello-service-config"
        class="org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.config.internal.HelloServiceConfig"
        init-method="startup"
        destroy-method="shutdown">
</bean>

<service ref="hello-service-config" interface="org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.IHelloService" />


<reference id="hello-service-config-admin" interface="org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin"
           availability="optional">
    <reference-listener bind-method="setConfigAdmin"
                        unbind-method="unsetConfigAdmin">
        <ref component-id="hello-service-config"/>
    </reference-listener>
</reference>
```

I have a reference to the ConfigurationAdmin service so, now I can check all properties for my bundle as:

```
public void setConfigAdmin(ConfigurationAdmin cfgAdmin) {
    this.cfgAdmin = cfgAdmin;
    try {
        Configuration cfg =   cfgAdmin.getConfiguration("org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.config");
        Dictionary<String, Object> properties = cfg.getProperties();
        Enumeration<String> en = properties.keys();
        while(en.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = en.nextElement();

            System.out.println("KEY: " + key + " VAL: " + properties.get(key));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As my 'update-strategy' is `reload` I can get updated whenever a new ConfigurationAdmin service is registered.

Any comment about my approach is welcome!

Comment: You can also use  have a class that `implements ConfigurationListener, BundleContextAware` interfaces. Then you'll receive all events regarding configuration changes, thus you can process whatever you want in your application

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property in karaf shell :

1/ `config:edit org.jemz.karaf.tutorial.hello.service.config`

2/ `config:propset <key> <value>`

3/ finally `config:update` to save change to file.

If you want to do it programatically, check karaf source to see the implementation

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution works, the properties are stored in the Properties place holder and I can list them. The problem is that my bundle cannot get those new properties. I think it is related to the bean definition I have only set one property to be injected "org.jemz,karaf.tutorial.service.msg" thus I cannot get more properties in my `setHelloServiceConfiguration` method. I have figured out another way of getting new properties from my config files I will post it in my answer. Anyway I will give you an upvote for the idea

Comment: Hi Jorge, if you are using SpringDM I can give you sample of configuration to be able to have multiple configuration files managed for one bundle