# Accessing properties in Karaf cfg file from java?

Tags: osgi, config, karaf, blueprint, property-placeholder

I am using cm:property-placeholder in blueprint to load config file:

```
<!-- External configuration -->
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="mubyndle" update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="schemaValidation" value="false"/> 
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>

<bean id="myBean" class="com.mybean">
    <property name="abc" value="${abc}" />
</bean>
```

I can set values into beans, like ${abc}. 
How can I access any other property of the config from java?

I am planning to add list of properties:
prop1=11
prop2=22
...
propn=nn

I cannot add all in blueprint as the number varies.

Thank you,
Viktor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add reference to ConfigurationAdmin service in blueprint:
    `<reference id="configAdmin" interface="org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin" />`

Set it to bean:
`<bean id="myBean" class="com.mybean">
    <property name="abc" value="${abc}" />
    <property name="configAdmin" ref="configAdmin" />
</bean>`

In bean:
`private ConfigurationAdmin configAdmin;`

```
public void setConfigAdmin(ConfigurationAdmin configAdmin) throws IOException {
    this.configAdmin = configAdmin;

    System.out.println(configAdmin);
    System.out.println(configAdmin.getConfiguration("any-persistent-id").getProperties());
}
```

Comment: You can have a look also to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043163/karaf-add-additional-property-to-existing-config-file/33085204#comment54127110_33085204

Answer (score 1):

You can set `org.apache.aries.blueprint.compendium.cm.CmPropertyPlaceholder` 
into myBean as `<property name="cmpp" ref="cmpp" />` 
after giving it id `<cm:property-placeholder id="cmpp" ...`.

Then add setter in myBean for cmpp:
`public void setProperties(CmPropertyPlaceholder properties) {
           Configuration config = CmUtils.getConfiguration(properties.getConfigAdmin(), properties.getPersistentId());
            if (config != null) {
                Dictionary props = config.getProperties();
                System.out.println(props);
            }`

The only problem is bundle `org.apache.aries.blueprint.cm` does not export package `org.apache.aries.blueprint.compendium.cm`, so I can't access `CmPropertyPlaceholder` in java. Is there any command in karaf that would additionally export a package of a bundle?

It is possible to access configuration through context, will look into that and post.

Answer (score 0):

You better do this:

a) in blueprint.xml

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.1.0"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
```

...

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="<name of cfg file>"
    update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="<property name in file>" value="<value>" />
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>


<bean id="<name of Bean>" class="<full name of class>" >
    <property name="<property name in file>" value="${<value>}"></property>
</bean>
```

b) inside "bean"

- define a public constructor (definition required by Spring)
- define a variable and its Setter:

> ```
> private <Type of> <name of variable>;
> public <Constructor> (){} // no parameters
> public void  set<property name in file first upper letter>(<Type of> <property name in file>) {
>   <name of variable> = <property name A>;
> }
> ```

c) add into '/etc' folder the configuration file:

> `<name of cfg file>.cfg`

Obviously, within it, the property:

> `<Property name> = <value>`

Comment: The question was how to set list of values, that are not comma separated but defined one per line in config file.